# Как автоматически создать диаграммы классов кода?

Tags: uml, reverse-engineering

Как построить полную диаграмму классов .NET кода (Class diagram) и диаграмму основных путей выполнения кода (Activity diagram, Workflow) ?

Какой софт позволяет наилучшим образом решать подобные задачи автоматически (или полуавтоматически), чтобы уменьшить количество ручной работы?

На данный момент используется встроенный редактор диаграмм Visual Studio, но его возможностей не хватает (очень желателен экспорт диаграмм в векторные графические форматы).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я порекомендую вам то, чем сам пользуюсь [Software Ideas Modeler](https://www.softwareideas.net/en/about/). Он бесплатен для некомерческого использования и имеет очень богатый функционал.